# How do I insert a boolean value into a postgresql database with heroku console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to change a record from false to true using the heroku console.

Everything I have tried gives the same error.

I have tried it like this:

```
entry.boolean = true
entry.save
```

It always gives this error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
```

What should I try next?

here is the full error from the console:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.9)
irb(main):001:0> entry = RegisterEntry.first
  RegisterEntry Load (53.6ms)  SELECT "register_entries".* FROM "register_entries" LIMIT 1
=> #<RegisterEntry id: 5, checkout: "2012-10-03", checkin: "2012-12-23", notes: "", publisher_id: 42, territory_id: 79, created_at: "2012-12-23 20:52:06", updated_at: "2012-12-23 20:54:27", written: false>
irb(main):002:0> entry.written = true
=> true
irb(main):003:0> entry.save
   (2.1ms)  BEGIN
   (2.5ms)  UPDATE "register_entries" SET "written" = 't', "updated_at" = '2012-12-24 12:32:45.224914' WHERE "register_entries"."id" = 5
  Territory Load (17.2ms)  SELECT "territories".* FROM "territories" WHERE "territories"."id" = 79 LIMIT 1
  Publisher Load (18.7ms)  SELECT "publishers".* FROM "publishers" WHERE "publishers"."id" = 42 LIMIT 1
   (3.5ms)  ROLLBACK
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
    from /app/app/models/register_entry.rb:30:in `delete'
    from /app/app/models/register_entry.rb:30:in `block in <class:RegisterEntry>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__731746304271343388__update__2234592017401079067__callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_update_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:272:in `update'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__731746304271343388__save__2234592017401079067__callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
    from (irb):3
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that exception? And are you using the same database in development and at Heroku?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 in development and postgresql in production. It does seem to work in development.

Comment: Could you show us the RegisterEntry model? There seems to be something wrong around line #30.

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning how to read the traces. Your comment helped me fix this. I had an ```update_after``` in my model. I fixed line 30 for this type of "updating through the console" case. If you want to put this in an answer then I will select yours as correct.

Comment: Stop using SQLite in development if you're using PostgreSQL in production; defaulting to SQLite might be the worst decision the Rails developers ever made, it causes no end of problems. SQLite has a very loose type system and it will let you get away with all sorts of dodgy things; PostgreSQL is rather unforgiving of shenanigans and that's an admirable quality in a database: a stern and strict database is a good database.

Answer (score 0):

try `entry.update_attribute(:boolean, true)`

Comment: can you show how your schema? or type `RegisterEntry` in the console and show the output

Comment: `````irb(main):004:0> RegisterEntry
=> RegisterEntry(id: integer, checkout: date, checkin: date, notes: string, publisher_id: integer, territory_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, written: boolean)`````

Comment: try to restart the server maybe?

Comment: @Jiří Pospíšil 's comment above helped me to fix this.  thanks for your help too.